Trouble with GoogleCredentials on Server
I’m facing an issue where my GoogleCredentials work perfectly fine on my local machine but don’t on the server. I’m using the following code:
InputStream credentialsStream = createJsonFile(keyFileStream);
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream)
.createScoped(
Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")
);

Problem:
It works locally, but on the server, it doesn't work. It gets stuck at this step without any error message.
Anyone else faced this issue or have any solutions?
More specific :
The issue occurs specifically at this step:
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);

It neither returns anything nor throws an error, and I don't get a credentials object."
I have tried running the code on my local machine, and it works perfectly fine, so I assume that the credential file and API scopes are correctly configured in my local environment.
My expectation is that the code will work on both my local machine and the server in the same way, as they both use the same credentials and configuration.

Which server do you use? A compute engine?

@Guillau It is in CLUJ vmware and is on prem k8s deployment

Did you try to run the packaging in another folder locally? You might have a wrong packaging with Java

Yes, I tried, but it didn't work.
The issue occurs specifically at this step:
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
It neither returns anything nor throws an error, and I don't get a credentials object.

I think you must have your service account key file packaged in your JAR, in the resource part.
But I don't like this. I don't like service account key file, but in your case, because you are running your code outside Google Cloud, you do not have many options...
My recommendation here would be to do this:

Do not load the service account key file in your code, and leverage ADC instead

ADC mean you ask for the default credential coming from the runtime environment. In your code, you simply do this:
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();


Set the absolute path of your service account key file in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var

Like this, your code do not embed the authentication part. It's the environment runtime, your VMware server, that load the credential for you.
There are many advantages to this:

You can run the same code in many environment without mixing dev, prod and acceptance service account. Each VM has its own key, no risk of cross env issue
You can commit your code safely. The service account key file, which is a sensitive secret, is not in the code repository
Only OPS will handle the secret. They have tools and best practices for this, not the devs (sadly....)


The key file will vary for each user. I am using this key file to generate an access token on behalf of the user, as suggested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709724/how-do-i-create-an-access-token-from-service-account-credentials-using-rest-api
Is there any other way to generate an access token using a JSON key file?

A key by user??? It's not scalable! and it's strange! What are the requirements/constraints that lead you to make this choice?

My requirement is to fetch data from a user bucket. To achieve this, I need to generate an access token using a service account JSON key file.

And are you sending the access token to the user? to the frontend?

Using that token to call other APIs to access user data.
